# The correct way to refer to a drop list on a computer window?

Tags: orthography

For example:

> Type in the description for the event (or use the **droplist** to choose one of the predefined choices).

My spellchecker is offering:

- drop list
- drop-list

Isn't **droplist** valid?

Comment: drop-down menu or drop-down list

Comment: Please google all the alternatives and let us know.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Questions about specialized terminology will often attract better answers from subject matter experts; I might ask this on our sister site, [ux.SE].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strictly speaking, this is more of a computer-related site question than one of English. However, they are commonly referred to as **dropdown lists**.

From [usability.gov](https://www.usability.gov/how-to-and-tools/methods/user-interface-elements.html):

> Dropdown lists allow users to select one item at a time, similarly to radio buttons, but are more compact allowing you to save space. Consider adding text to the field, such as ‘Select one’ to help the user recognize the necessary action.

It's a matter of style if it should be *dropdown* or *drop-down*, although the unhyphenated version seems more common.